# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS can't find my wireless card or the network after I shutdown and turn my system back on

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

Ubuntu boots up and doesn't find any available wireless network and it doesn't recognize my wireless card either. However, when I open the terminal and type: `sudo modprobe b43` it finds my wireless card and all of the available networks around me and everything is cool... until I shutdown my system.

When I shutdown and then turn my computer back on it completely forgets about the network I just found and told it to connect automatically to. So, back to the terminal to find the wireless card and networks manually. Every. Single. Time.

How do I configure my system so that I don't have to manually find the wireless card and connect to my network every time I restart my computer?

OUTPUT from TERMINAL:

```
root@jake-XPS-M1530:/home/jake# dmesg | grep b43
[    8.684953] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[    8.728075] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[   20.116128] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
root@jake-XPS-M1530:/home/jake#
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `echo b43 | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`. That should make sure the b43 module gets autoloaded, and your wifi should work after shutdowns.

Comment: should I run that in root terminal?

Comment: You don't have to. Running is as a user with admin rights should work as well.

Comment: I opened a terminal and ran the code. I restarted my system and it still doesn't automatically connect.

Comment: That's odd. Check that it got added to /etc/modules with `cat /etc/modules`.

Comment: This is what it shows after I execute the command cat /etc/modules





root@jake-XPS-M1530:/home/jake# cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rtc
b43
b43
b43
b43
b43
root@jake-XPS-M1530:/home/jake#

Comment: Sorry about the formatting here. The message box doesn't seem to let me break the lines where I choose. It just lumps everything together apparently.

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question, and add properly formatted outputs. Try adding the output of `dmesg | grep b43` now. Anyway, b43 is in /etc/modules at least five times, so please edit the file and remove the redundant entries.